# Unable to connect to PostgreSQL server: missing "=" after "Resource"

Tags: php, postgresql

Can anybody help me with this error? I'm try to connect my `PHP 7.0.8` to `PostgreSQL 9.6`.

pg_connect(): Unable to connect to PostgreSQL server: missing "=" after "Resource" in connection info string

`$db = pg_connect("host=localhost port=5432 dbname=xxx user=postgres password=xxx") or die('connection failed');`

Comment: What language or scripting language/terminal is this?

Comment: PHP? I just follow the documentation: http://php.net/manual/en/function.pg-pconnect.php

Comment: Are you able to make this connection in other ways, like with pgAdmin or psql?

Comment: Thanks to all. I just solved my problem. I just changed `pg_connect` to `pg_pconnect`. I used an deprecated function.