# My database connection doesn't connect with postgreSQL

Tags: php, postgresql, codeigniter

the code is written for the connection but the function pg_connect() doesn't work with the framework and database i.e. codeigniter and postgreSQL.

to connect with database i have written the code for the config/database.php
but the error is persistent that the connection is unable to connect.

i completed the information for the config/database.php file 
the details are complete and provided as per requirement for the database connection.

```
$active_group = 'default';
$query_builder = TRUE;

$db['default'] = array(
    'dsn'   => 'localhost',
    'hostname' => 'localhost',
    'username' => 'puneetchhabra',
    'password' => 'shambhu',
    'database' => 'success_story',
    'dbdriver' => 'postgre',
    'port' => '',
    'dbprefix' => '',
    'pconnect' => FALSE,
    'db_debug' => (ENVIRONMENT !== 'production'),
    'cache_on' => FALSE,
    'cachedir' => '',
    'char_set' => 'utf8',
    'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
    'swap_pre' => '',
    'encrypt' => FALSE,
    'compress' => FALSE,
    'stricton' => FALSE,
    'failover' => array(),
    'save_queries' => TRUE
);
```

error message

> Severity: Warning
>
> Message: pg_connect(): Unable to connect to PostgreSQL server: missing
>   "=" after "localhost" in connection info string
>
> Filename: postgre/postgre_driver.php
>
> Line Number: 154
>
> Unable to connect to your database server using the provided settings.
>
> Filename: core/CodeIgniter.php
>
> Line Number: 518

Comment: based on [this qa](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41780893/4648586), try `pg_pconnect()` instead if you made such calls. try to [empty the dsn](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40208787/4648586) also. a lot you can try, just [keep searching](https://stackoverflow.com/search).

Answer (score 0):

Take out the DSN.  You should generally use either an array of parameters, or a DSN string, not both.